# Fill string with numbers from 0 to 9 and start new until length is 50

Tags: c#, arrays, string

So I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793415/get-sub-string-of-nth-from-a-string-less-or-greater-length-than-n-in-c-sharp) today. Now I thought a bit further and came up with the following scenario:

```
string myString = "Hello";
int[] numbersFromZeroToNine = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

I want to add the numbers from `numbersFromZeroToNine` to `myString` (with restarting at position `0`) until `myString` has a length of 50. If `myString` already is longer than 50 characters, I want to print out the first 50 chars.

I could achieve it by using the following lines:

```
if (myString.Length >= 50)
    myString = myString.Substring(0, 50);
else
{
    for (int counter = 0; myString.Length < 50; counter++)
    {
        if (counter == numbersFromZeroToNine.Count())
            counter = 0;
        myString += numbersFromZeroToNine[counter];
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(myString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Result:

> Hello012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234

As you see, I could do it with using a `for` loop and an `if` statement inside the `else`. But I don't think this is the nicest (and shortest) approach for this scenario. That's what I wanted to ask you now: Is there a shorter solution to achieve the same result?

Comment: I suppose you could use recursion, but I'm not sure if it would be considered *shorter*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terser, but I'm afraid, less readable *Linq* solution:

```
  string prefix = "Hello";
  int length = 50;

  // Hello012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
  string result = prefix + 
    new string(Enumerable
                .Range(0, length - prefix.Length)
                .Select(c => (Char) ('0' + c % 10))
                .ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice solution, although it's less readable. Didn't think about using Linq for this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this LINQ approach which  uses am indefinit sequence of numbers. A nice demonstration of LINQ's deferred execution:

```
IEnumerable<char> numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(numbersFromZeroToNine, int.MaxValue)
    .SelectMany(intArr => intArr)
    .Select(i => i.ToString()[0]);
if (myString.Length < 50)
{
    var chars = myString.ToCharArray().Concat(numbers).Take(50);
    myString = String.Concat(chars);
}
```

But it would be easier to store a `char[]` in the first place:

```
char[] digits = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
IEnumerable<char> myChars = myString; // needed to avoid that String.Concat will be used
var infiniteDigits = Enumerable.Repeat(digits, int.MaxValue).SelectMany(arr => arr);
if (myString.Length < 50)
    myString = String.Concat(myChars.Concat(infiniteDigits).Take(50));
```

Comment: This might work but I think it's even less readable than the solutions in the other answers.

Comment: @diiN_: maybe, but it is more generic  and also shows how to use LINQ's deferred execution to get an indefinite repetition of the same sequence without really generating it. You can change `Take(50)` to whatever length you want.

Comment: Using the `Take` is a clever way to avoid writing that loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using LINQ and `string.Concat` and modulo (`%`):

```
myString += string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 50 - myString.Length).Select(i => i % 10));
```

But if this is *nicer* is rather opinion based. And if it's *faster* is to be measured.

Answer (score 2):

See code below:

```
var str = "Hello";
str += new string(Enumerable.Range(0, 50 - str.Length)
      .Select(i => (char)('0' + (i % 10))).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use both `Range` and `Repeat` to make it concise and avoid writing that `foreach` loop in favor of LINQ:

```
var prefix = "Hello";
var numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10), 
        (50 - prefix.Length) / Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Count() + 1)
    .SelectMany (e => e.Select (x => x)).ToArray();

var myString = (prefix + 
    string.Join("", numbers.Select (n => n.ToString()))).Substring(0, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variation on the same theme, but using StringBuilder and an old-fashioned for loop.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder("Hello");
for(var i=0; builder.Length<50; ++i) { builder.Append((char)('0'+(i%10))); }
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```